# Google App Engine log username with custom auth

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging

I use a custom authentication for my python Google App Engine app.
There is a "username" field in the log for every request, which is empty now. Is it possible to add the name of the authenticated user to the log? I would not like to add an `"user: %s" % user.name` manually to all of my logging.xxx statements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a single `logging.debug` call in your authentication code to log the current user. Logs are shown aggregated by request, so you'll always be able to see the user associated with that request.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to use the `user:XXX` filtering in the log browser to see where the user go on my site.

Comment: Or is there any better log viewer which I can use for GAE?

Comment: @psmith You should be able to filter on the contents of a log message. If not, then there's no way around this. You can download logs from App Engine using appcfg, and process them however you wish.

Comment: @nick-johnson Downloaded log looks good, but not easy to grep. But thanks.